# security decision from a JWT in a spring rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm using Spring with oauth2 that release a JWT token.
I have a working prototype on which I can use the @PreAuthorize annotation for my purposes.

```
// public class Foo { private String md5Hash; } with getters, setters, etc.

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class WebController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('client','module')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String readFoo(Foo foo) {
        String username = /* extract jwt info */
        if (verify(username, foo.getMd5Hash())) 
             return "you CAN'T";
        return "you can";
    }

    boolean verify(String user, String md5) {...}
```

In the JWT token is defined the user name.
How can I read the user name from here?

Moreover, as you can see, I have another security decision to take... is this a good way or there's some Spring feature that I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT token will be sent in the **Authorization** http header property while requesting like,

**Authorization: Bearer {jwt-token}**

you can access the http header in Request Mapping like,

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('client','module')")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String readFoo(Foo foo, @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String bearerToken) {
    // you can use any JWT libraries return object version of jwt
    String username = extractJwtToken(bearerToken);
}
```

check this site https://jwt.io/, to find out available java libraries to use and regarding,

**I have another security decision to take**

Yes you have to, JWT claims only contains what it can do, and you need to do authorization, checking whether a user(token) has sufficient privilege or access to do specific operations, and it has to be done from your end only, its part of business logic.